# JS. В чем преимущества/недостатки "контекстного"/объектного стиля программирования

Tags: javascript

В чем преимущества того или иного подхода при реализации кода, объясните пожалуйста.

1. Используя **this**:

   ```
   function totalControl() {

     this.firstMethod = function () {}
     this.secondMethod = function () {}

   }
   ```
2. Используя **объект**:

   ```
   var totalControl = {

     firstMethod : function () {}
     secondMethod : function () {}

   }
   ```

Comment: в первом литерал - это уже готовый объект, а во втором случае функцию в виде конструктора нужно вызвать непосредственно. В принципе разницы нет